# Using application.properties with non-bean class

Tags: java, spring, devops, application.properties

I have the following class that is not a Spring bean:

```
public class NotBean implements NotBeanInterface {

   @Override
   public void relevantMethod() {
      System.out.println(Config.CONSTANT); // some value, enum or static
   }
}
```

And also the following Spring bean that uses the above:

```
@Service
public class FooBean {

  public void foo() {
    new NotBean().relevantMethod();
  }
}
```

Everything is fine, but it turns out there are multiple environments. For production, I need `Config.CONSTANT` to be equal `10`. And for another environment I need it to be `20`.

Therefore I thought about moving out this config from enum/static to `application.properties`.

The problem is, I cannot use `application.properties` in a `NotBean` non-bean class.

This situation seems quite ordinary, how should it be handled?

Comment: I suggest to move all required fields which depend on spring app properties to NotBean constructor.

Comment: Or you can create prototype bean, create "provider" for it, and use this provider in your service: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton#javax_api

Comment: Anyway I think, that it's bad idea try to use spring application config directly from your POJO.